# PowerQuery Working W/ Duplicates and Combining Unique Lines

Tags: powerquery

when combining duplicates, you are left with unique lines (which is great) but now I am looking for ways to combine this info into one line. Here is a sample data:

Current:

| Person | Member | Alum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | null | Y |
| A | Y | null |
| B | null | Y |
| B | Y | null |
| B | Y | Y |
| Z | null | null |

Goal:

| Person | Member | Alum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | Y | Y |
| B | Y | Y |
| Z | null | null |

Comment: Did any of these answers work for you?

Comment: @horseyride, yours worked. I just marked it. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about below, assuming null means it is a null value and not the text "null", and there is only ever one unique value option

```
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"Person"}, {
    {"Member", each try List.RemoveNulls(List.Distinct(_[Member])){0} otherwise null},
    {"Alum", each try  List.RemoveNulls(List.Distinct(_[Alum])){0} otherwise null}
    })
in #"Grouped Rows"
```

Comment: You could also try a variation on: `{"Member", each Text.Combine(List.Distinct([Member])), type nullable text}` for the  aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

This is my work, made to match the desired output table layout.
Source is 'Table1'.

```
    let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    Custom1 = Table.AddColumn(Source, "MemberY", each try(if Character.ToNumber([Member])=89 then 1 else 0) otherwise 0),
    Custom2 = Table.AddColumn(Custom1, "AlumY", each try(if Character.ToNumber([Alum])=89 then 1 else 0) otherwise 0),
    OtherColumnsRemoved = Table.SelectColumns(Custom2,{"Person", "MemberY", "AlumY"}),
    GrouedRows = Table.Group(OtherColumnsRemoved, {"Person"}, {{"Member", each List.Max([MemberY]), type number}, {"Alum", each List.Max([AlumY]), type number}}),
    ChangedType1 = Table.TransformColumnTypes(GrouedRows,{{"Member", type text}, {"Alum", type text}}),
    ChangedValue = Table.ReplaceValue(ChangedType1,"1","Y",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Member", "Alum"}),
    FinalTable = Table.ReplaceValue(ChangedValue,"0","NULL",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Member", "Alum"})
in
    FinalTable
```